# How to encode strings with EncdDec library

Tags: delphi

I have this basic code that should encode a string and then get it back. However, the decoded text is garbage.

```
procedure TForm5.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR s1, s2, s3: String;
    i: Integer;
begin
 for i:= 1 to 200
  DO s1:= s1+ char(Random(255));

 s1:= EncdDecd.EncodeString(s1);
 s3:= EncdDecd.DecodeString(s2);

 if s1= s3
 then Caption:= 'Equal'
 else Caption:= 'Not equal';
end;
```

---

**Update:**
It works if I do char(Random(128)) instead of 255!

Comment: By "is garbage" I'm assuming you mean `s1` and `s2` don't match, right? Because you are dumping in random characters; garbage in, garbage out :-)

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984247/making-a-base64-decoded-text-visible-without-changing-windows-language-for-non

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here, in the `Soap.EncdDecd` unit:

```
function EncodeString(const Input: string): string;
var
  InStr, OutStr: TStringStream;
begin
  InStr := TStringStream.Create(Input);
  try
    OutStr := TStringStream.Create('');
    try
      EncodeStream(InStr, OutStr);
      Result := OutStr.DataString;
    finally
      OutStr.Free;
    end;
  finally
    InStr.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This code has not been updated for Unicode. The use of `TStringStream` for `InStr` without specifying an encoding is the problem. With no encoding specified, ANSI is used to decode to a byte array. And so only characters in the local ANSI code page are decoded correctly.

The same mistake is made in the other direction in `DecodeString`.

You can fix this readily enough by creating variants that specify a full Unicode encoding. For example:

```
function EncodeString(const Input: string): string;
var
  InStr, OutStr: TStringStream;
begin
  InStr := TStringStream.Create(Input, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    OutStr := TStringStream.Create('');
    try
      EncodeStream(InStr, OutStr);
      Result := OutStr.DataString;
    finally
      OutStr.Free;
    end;
  finally
    InStr.Free;
  end;
end;

function DecodeString(const Input: string): string;
var
  InStr, OutStr: TStringStream;
begin
  InStr := TStringStream.Create(Input);
  try
    OutStr := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      DecodeStream(InStr, OutStr);
      Result := OutStr.DataString;
    finally
      OutStr.Free;
    end;
  finally
    InStr.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It doesn't matter which encoding you specify so long as it is a full Unicode encoding, and you use the same encoding in both directions!

Clearly Embarcadero should be encouraged to make this change to their code.

This program demonstrates that the fix works:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Soap.EncdDecd;

function EncodeString(const Input: string): string;
var
  InStr, OutStr: TStringStream;
begin
  InStr := TStringStream.Create(Input, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    OutStr := TStringStream.Create('');
    try
      EncodeStream(InStr, OutStr);
      Result := OutStr.DataString;
    finally
      OutStr.Free;
    end;
  finally
    InStr.Free;
  end;
end;

function DecodeString(const Input: string): string;
var
  InStr, OutStr: TStringStream;
begin
  InStr := TStringStream.Create(Input);
  try
    OutStr := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      DecodeStream(InStr, OutStr);
      Result := OutStr.DataString;
    finally
      OutStr.Free;
    end;
  finally
    InStr.Free;
  end;
end;

const
  N = 256;

var
  i: Integer;
  s1, s2: string;

begin
  SetLength(s1, N);
  for i := 1 to N do
    s1[i] := Chr(i-1);

  s2 := Soap.EncdDecd.EncodeString(s1);
  s2 := Soap.EncdDecd.DecodeString(s2);
  Writeln(s1=s2);

  s2 := EncodeString(s1);
  s2 := DecodeString(s2);
  Writeln(s1=s2);
end.
```

Output:

```
FALSE
TRUE
```

Comment: Maybe this code should be given to EMBT so they can sell a good product ;) And David Heffernan receive some free licenses for fixing the bugs which they don't care. Simple as that! @Marco Cantu - can I split the licenses with David? Thank you

Comment: @RBA-Well, a simple mention at the top of the unit that 'string' is not actually (unicode) string would have been sufficient.

Comment: @Altar I presume the reason why it is not commented is because nobody tested properly. The code was fine in ANSI Delphi. It compiles fine in Unicode Delphi. Probably the test cases (if they have any) were incomplete. And so it slipped under the radar. If the devs at Emba became aware of the issue then I guess they would apply a fix like mine. It is worth writing a QC report.

Comment: There is a QC rep. It is closed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Since you are using UTF8, will it work with 'high' characters also? For example, can I use: chr(Random(65535))? I cannot test this right now.

Comment: Base64 encodes binary to a 64 character subset of ASCII. So the first step is to decode the string to some binary. That's done with `TEncoding.GetBytes`. So long as you have a full Unicode encoding, this produces reversible output for all characters. You can use UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 or indeed some as yet uninvented encoding so long as it is complete. Then from those bytes to base64 and back again is simple enough. Finally, to get back to string you reverse the Unicode step.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick** fix:

ANSI is enough for me since the text resulted after encoding must be as short as possible (easy to send via email). So, I put my ANSI string into a stream and encoded/decoded the stream. It worked!

---

Jesus. Some documentation (at least a single comment line) would have been nice!