# BASE64 Encode and Decode is not working

Tags: android, delphi, base64, delphi-xe5

I am working on android applicatin in Delphi XE5 and I need to BASE64 encode and decode some strings.

This function is working fine for english characters, but what I want to encode €, $ or any special iso8859-2 characters encoding doesn't work.

**Any idea how to fix it?**

I found BASE64 unit http://www.delphipraxis.net/991-base64-mime-en-decoding.html

But does FireMonkey support AnsiString and PAnsiChar type and what unit to include to use this type?

My code

```
uses IdCoderMIME;
...

function Encode64(S: string): string;
var
  IdEncoderMIME: TIdEncoderMIME;
begin
  try
    IdEncoderMIME := TIdEncoderMIME.Create(nil);
    Result := IdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(S);
  finally
    IdEncoderMIME.Free;
  end;
end;

function Decode64(S: string): string;
var
  IdDecoderMIME: TIdDecoderMIME;
var
  IdDecoderMIME: TIdDecoderMIME;
begin
  try
    IdDecoderMIME := TIdDecoderMIME.Create(nil);
    Result := IdDecoderMIME.DecodeString(S);
  finally
    IdDecoderMIME.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: BASE64 is a string representation for a bunch of bytes. To get the bytes from a string you also have to look at the encoding (ASCII, ANSI, UTF8, ...) of the string and what encoding does the target support/expect. [`TEncoding.GetBytes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding.GetBytes). BTW This is **not** related to FireMonkey

Comment: Are you using Indy in your app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Officially*, Delphi **DOES NOT** support `AnsiString` and `(P)AnsiChar` on mobile platforms.  *Unofficially*, the support code for them is still present in the compiler and RTL, it is just hidden so you cannot access it anymore.  There is a [third-party patch](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2013/10/the-return-of-the-byte-strings/) available that re-enables access.

When encoding/decoding a string, you have to take character encoding into account.  Base64 encodes bytes, not characters.  You have to convert a string to a byte sequence before then Base64 encoding the bytes, and then Base64 decode the byte sequence before then converting it back to a string.

The `TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString()` and `TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeString()` methods have an optional `TIdTextEncoding` or `IIdTextEncoding` parameter (depending on your version of Indy) for that string<->bytes conversion.  If you do not specify a text encoding, Indy will use its default text encoding, which is 7bit ASCII by default (configurable via the `IdGlobal.GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable).

For example:

```
uses
  ..., IdGlobal, IdCoderMIME;

function Encode64(const S: string: const ByteEncoding: IIdTextEncoding = nil): string;
begin
  Result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(S, ByteEncoding);
end;

function Decode64(const S: string: const ByteEncoding: IIdTextEncoding = nil): string;
begin
  Result := TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeString(S, ByteEncoding);
end;
```

```
uses
  ..., IdGlobal;

var
  s, base64: string;
begin
  s := '€$';
  base64 := Encode64(s, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  s := Decode64(base64, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
end;
```

```
uses
  ..., IdGlobal;

var
  s, base64: string;
  enc: IIdTextEncoding;
begin
  enc := IndyTextEncoding(28592); // ISO-8859-2
  s := '€$';
  base64 := Encode64(s, enc);
  s := Decode64(base64, enc);
end;
```

```
uses
  ..., IdGlobal, IdGlobalProtocols;

var
  s, base64: string;
  enc: IIdTextEncoding;
begin
  enc := CharsetToEncoding('ISO-8859-2');
  s := '€$';
  base64 := Encode64(s, enc);
  s := Decode64(base64, enc);
```

Answer (score 7):

The key point is that base64 is an encoding of byte arrays to text. So if you wish to encode text, you must first transform the text into a byte array. And to do so you need to pick a specific text encoding.

For the sake of example, let us suppose that your text encoding is UTF-8. The procedure for encoding text to base64 runs like this:

1. Encode the plain text into a byte array using the UTF-8 encoding.
2. Encode that byte array into a base64 string.

In the opposite direction it goes like this:

1. Decode the base64 string into a byte array.
2. Decode the byte array to a string using the UTF-8 encoding.

Delphi ships with libraries that can perform all of these steps. The `TEncoding` class handles the UTF-8 part, and the `Soap.EncdDecd` unit does base64. There is no need to use Indy here just to perform base64 encoding.

Unfortunately the `EncodeString` and `DecodeString` functions in `Soap.EncdDecd` [do not handle Unicode correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883152/). I prefer to avoid them and do it all using the `EncodeStream` and `DecodeStream` functions. Like this:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Soap.EncdDecd;

function EncodeString(const Input: string): string;
var
  InStr, OutStr: TStringStream;
begin
  InStr := TStringStream.Create(Input, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    OutStr := TStringStream.Create('');
    try
      EncodeStream(InStr, OutStr);
      Result := OutStr.DataString;
    finally
      OutStr.Free;
    end;
  finally
    InStr.Free;
  end;
end;

function DecodeString(const Input: string): string;
var
  InStr, OutStr: TStringStream;
begin
  InStr := TStringStream.Create(Input);
  try
    OutStr := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      DecodeStream(InStr, OutStr);
      Result := OutStr.DataString;
    finally
      OutStr.Free;
    end;
  finally
    InStr.Free;
  end;
end;
```