# send and recive TStringStream with indyTcp server and client

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I am trying to send a `TStringStream` from client to server, then send it back from server to client, using Indy TCP components.

Here is my client code:

```
var
  Jpg: TJPEGImage;
  StringStream: TStringStream;
  strcams, StringImageData: String;
  byt, i: integer;

procedure SendCommandWithParams(Command, Params: String);
begin
  Lock;
  try
    if not FTCP.Connected then
    begin
      exit;
    end;
    FTCP.Socket.WriteLn('1' + Command, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
    FTCP.Socket.WriteLn(Params, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  finally
    Unlock;
  end;
end;

begin
  Jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
  StringStream := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    try
      Jpg.Performance := jpBestSpeed;
      Jpg.ProgressiveEncoding := True;
      Jpg.ProgressiveDisplay := True;
      Jpg.Assign(Image2.Picture.Bitmap);
      Jpg.CompressionQuality := 25;
      Jpg.Compress;
      Jpg.SaveToStream(StringStream);
      StringImageData := StringStream.DataString;
      strcams := '<[S:' + IntToStr(Length(StringImageData)) + 'B]>' +
        StringImageData;
      if Length(strcams) < byt then
      begin
       SendCommandWithParams('SIMGSEND', strcams + sep + 'IMGID5423' + sep);
      end;
    except
      on e: exception do
        //
    end;
  finally
    StringImageData := '';
    FreeAndNil(Jpg);
    FreeAndNil(StringStream);
  end;
end;
```

I can receive the `TStringStream` data, but the data received is corrupted, and some times it gets replaced with the second parameter that I send which is  `'IMGID5423' + sep`.  I am not sure if this is because of some limit of packet sending through TCP so the data does not arrive complete, or is this a parser issue?

My current parser should separate each text that ended with `#13#10`. Here is how it looks:

```
var
  ReceiveParams, ReceiveStream: Boolean;
  S: string;
  Command: String;
begin
  Command := Fholdcommand;
  ReceiveParams := false;
  ReceiveStream := false;

  if Command[1] = '1' then // command with params
  begin
    Command := Copy(Command, 2, MaxInt);
    ReceiveParams := True;
  end;

  if ReceiveParams then // params incomming
  begin
    S := FTCP.Socket.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
    FCMD := Command;
    FPRMS := S;
    FSTREAM := false;
    if Assigned(FOnCallbackProc) then
    begin
      Synchronize(DoCallbackProc);
    end;
  end;
```

I am still confused about the real issue.  I try to send the `TStringStream` in a local procedure, and it is received normally without any corruption.

Am I sending the data wrong altogether through Indy?

This is how I am receiving the data:

```
procedure CreateJpg(Data:string);
var
  StringStream : TStringStream;
  JpegImage : TJPEGImage;
  Bitmap : TBitmap;
  tmpPos:integer;
  pp:string;
  label check;
begin
  GData := Data;

  if LeftStr(GData,4) = '<[S:' then 
  begin
    tmpPos := Pos(WideString('B]>'),GData);
    pp := Copy(GData,5,tmpPos-5);
    CDataELen :=  StrToInt(pp); //MidStr(st,5,tmppos - 5);
    CData := RightStr(GData,length(GData)-(tmppos+2));
    goto check;
  end;

  CData := CData + GData;

  check:

  //if CDataELen = length(CData) then
  begin
    StringStream := TStringStream.Create('');
    JpegImage := TJpegImage.Create;
    StringStream.WriteString(CData);
    CData := '';
    try
      try
        StringStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
        JpegImage.LoadFromStream(StringStream);
        Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
        with Bitmap do
        begin
          Canvas.Lock;
          try
            Width := JpegImage.Width;
            Height := JpegImage.Height;
            Canvas.Draw(0, 0, JpegImage);
          finally
            Canvas.Unlock;
          end;
        end;

        img.Picture.Bitmap.Width := Bitmap.Width;
        img.Picture.Bitmap.Height := Bitmap.Height;
        img.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Bitmap);

      except
        on E: Exception do
          //
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(StringStream);
      FreeAndNil(JpegImage);
      FreeAndNil(Bitmap);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I see a lot of code like this with an exception handler that swallows exceptions. Why would you do that? Don't you think it is important to react to exceptions rather than ignoring them and hoping that your program will still work?

Comment: i log the exceptions on the disk i juts put empty comment there because it wasn't certain

Comment: Your edit defaced the question. I reverted it.

Comment: You can just send the jpgstream as is, not need for the TStringStream. Indy SendStream will handle sending stream length automatically for you

Comment: @whosrdaddy unless you want to maintain text comms for instance for ease of debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are saving the JPG binary data to a `TStringStream` and then letting it *reinterpret* the binary data as if it were string data.  You can't do that.  You need to save the JPG data to a binary stream instead, like `TMemoryStream`, and then *encode* the binary data using a string-safe encoding, like Base64.

Try something more like this instead:

```
uses
  ..., IdCoder, IdCoderMIME;

...

var
  Jpg: TJPEGImage;
  JpegStream: TMemoryStream;
  strcams, StringImageData: String;
begin
  try
    JpegStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
      try
        Jpg.Performance := jpBestSpeed;
        Jpg.ProgressiveEncoding := True;
        Jpg.ProgressiveDisplay := True;
        Jpg.Assign(Image2.Picture.Bitmap);
        Jpg.CompressionQuality := 25;
        Jpg.Compress;
        Jpg.SaveToStream(JpegStream);
      finally
        Jpg.Free;
      end;
      JpegStream.Position := 0;
      StringImageData := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(JpegStream);
    finally
      JpegStream.Free;
    end;
    strcams := '<[S:' + IntToStr(Length(StringImageData)) + 'B]>' + StringImageData;
    SendCommandWithParams('SIMGSEND', strcams + sep + 'IMGID5423' + sep);
  except
    on e: exception do
      //
  end;
end;
```

And then on the receiving end:

```
procedure CreateJpg(Data: string);
var
  JpegStream: TMemoryStream;
  JpegImage: TJPEGImage;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  tmpPos, tmpLen: integer;
  pp: string;
begin
  try
    if not TextStartsWith(Data, '<[S:') then
    begin
      // bad data, do something else...
      Exit;
    end;

    tmpPos := Pos('B]>', Data);
    pp := Copy(Data, 5, tmpPos-5);
    tmpLen := StrToInt(pp);
    Data := Copy(Data, tmpPos+3, tmpLen);

    Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      JpegImage := TJpegImage.Create;
      try
        JpegStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
        try
          TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeStream(Data, JpegStream);
          JpegStream.Position := 0;
          JpegImage.LoadFromStream(JpegStream);
        finally
          JpegStream.Free;
        end;
        with Bitmap do
        begin
          Canvas.Lock;
          try
            Width := JpegImage.Width;
            Height := JpegImage.Height;
            Canvas.Draw(0, 0, JpegImage);
          finally
            Canvas.Unlock;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        JpegImage.Free;
      end;
      img.Picture.Assign(Bitmap);
    finally
      Bitmap.Free;
    end;        
  except
    on E: Exception do
      //
  end;
end;
```

Comment: i shouldnt encode `strcams` ?  i used your code for base64 encoding here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026825/base64-encode-and-decode-is-not-working     i used `ByteEncoding` i tried to send same as you do but images comes blank i will update the question with the receiving code

Comment: You don't need to base64 encode `strcams` itself (you *can* if you want to, but you don't *need* to). Your whole protocol is string-based, and `strcams` only contains ASCII characters, no special encoding needed. As for the earlier code you linked to, it was meant for base64 encoding **string data** (by converting the string characters to charset-encoded bytes and then base64 encoding those bytes).  JPG is **binary data** instead. Use `EncodeStream()` instead of `EncodeString()` if you want to base64 encode **binary data**.

Comment: ok i will try out should i decode that encodedstream ? i mean i was decode `strcams` after its received on server

Comment: @Vlark.Lopin: yes, of course you have to decode the base64 that was inside of `strcams`.  I have added an example to my answer.

Comment: weird i used exactly the same code but i receive blank image should i remove the utf8 encoding from sending command to server ?

Comment: @Vlark.Lopin: it doesn't matter, since base64 is compatible with ASCII, and thus UTF-8. If you are getting blank images, you are still doing something wrong.  Please edit your question to show your latest code.

Comment: i will edit the question now and post the fill code server and client side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123301/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-vlark-lopin).

Comment: answer accepted as it gives me the actual solve my mistake was i was decode the data on server side as will

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be that you are treating binary data as though it is text. Binary data can contain anything, for instance `#13#10` line breaks or indeed anything whatsoever.

If you wish to send that data as text, then you need to use a text encoding. For example, encode it as base64.

Or transmit the content as binary rather than text.

Comment: i tried to use base64 to encode the binary data  . i received the image blank

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Don't expect us to debug your onward code.

Comment: i tried to compare the sended text and received one they are different i think i got encoding issue

Comment: No doubt. Use built in encoders. Either Emba's or Indy.

Comment: No you are in for some routine debugging. Prove that you can send and receive identical text. Prove that you can encode and decode that text. No need to transmit anything to test that. Factor your code well so that you can call different stages as you please.  Don't just bundle all the code into one function. Please do try to understand this site. It's a Q&A site. We aren't here to do your job for you.

Comment: i found the issue using indy encoding as utf8 send the data correctly thank you .

Comment: This pretty much epitomises what I dislike about the changes to this site over the past few years.