# Reading the data string From TStringStream

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I have an issue with `TStringStream` encoding on different OS region languages.

I am trying to transfer image data.  I was having a problem with it before, and it was solved in another question.

But now I have an encoding issue on `TStringStream` itself.  If the Operating System region language is set to English, I get corrupted data from `TStringStream`.

When I change the language to Arabic, the data comes out correctly.

I currently use Indy to encode the binary data, but before starting the encoding, the data from `StringStream.DataString` is already corrupted if the region encoding is not set to Arabic.  I tried to add `TEncoding.UTF8` to `TStringStream.Create()`, but the data still comes out incorrectly from `StringStream.DataString`.

```
function Encode64(const S: string; const ByteEncoding: IIdTextEncoding = nil): string;
begin
  Result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(S, ByteEncoding);
end;

function Decode64(const S: string; const ByteEncoding: IIdTextEncoding = nil): string;
begin
  Result := TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeString(S, ByteEncoding);
end;

StringStream := TStringStream.Create('');
try
  Jpg.Performance := jpBestSpeed;
  Jpg.ProgressiveEncoding := True;
  Jpg.ProgressiveDisplay := True;
  jpg.Assign(Image2.Picture.Bitmap);
  jpg.CompressionQuality := 25;
  jpg.Compress;
  jpg.SaveToStream(StringStream);
  StringImageData := StringStream.DataString; // the data here is corrupted when Os region is not set to arabic 
  strcams := '<[S:' + IntToStr(Length(StringImageData)) + 'B]>' + StringImageData;
  if length(strcams) < byt then begin
    Sendimgdata('IMGDATA123', Encode64(strcams, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8) + sep);
  end;
  ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot save a JPG to a `TStringStream` to begin with.  You need to encode the binary data without converting it to a string first, which will corrupt the data.  Use a `TMemoryStream` instead for the binary data:

```
MemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
...
jpg.SaveToStream(MemoryStream);
MemoryStream.Position := 0;
StringImageData := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(MemoryStream);
...
```

If you want to encode after you insert the text with length, you have to work with `TMemoryStream` too:

```
procedure StringToStream(aStream: TStream; const aString: AnsiString);
begin
  aStream.Write(PAnsiChar(AString)^, Length(AString));
end;

...

JpegStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
jpg.SaveToStream(JpegStream);

CompleteStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
StringToStream(CompleteStream, '<[S:' + IntToStr(JpegStream.Size)+'B]>');

CompleteStream.CopyFrom(JpegStream, 0);
StringImageData := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(CompleteStream);
```

Comment: FYI, Indy has `WriteStringToStream()` and `WriteMemoryStreamToStream()` functions in the `IdGlobal` unit

Comment: Right, that's an option too.

Comment: the string that will hold the stream should be like this `strcams :=  IntToStr(Length(StringImageData)) + StringImageData;`  ? also `intTostr(memorystream.size)` , should be jpg.size

Comment: @Vlark.Lopin: `jpg.size` is the wrong value to send. You should be sending the *encoded* size.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39476500/65863) to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39448538/).

Comment: i meant jpgstream.size

Comment: That depends on you how you manipulate your data. You can base64 encode whole string with length, or you can encode just jpeg data and then insert length.