# Delphi 7 and decode UTF-8 base64

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In Delphi 7, I have a widestring encoded with Base64(That I received from a Web service with WideString result) :

**PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8+DQo8c3RyaW5nPtiq2LPYqjwvc3RyaW5nPg==**

when I decoded it, that result is not UTF-8:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<string>طھط³طھ</string>
```

But when I decoded it by base64decode.org, result is true :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<string>تست</string>
```

I have use EncdDecd unit for DecodeString function.

Comment: Related question: [How to encode strings with EncdDec library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883152/how-to-encode-strings-with-encddec-library)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are using `DecodeString`. That function, in Delphi 7, treats the decoded binary data as being ANSI encoded. And the problem is that your text is UTF-8 encoded.

To continue with the `EncdDecd` unit you have a couple of options. You can switch to `DecodeStream`. For instance, this code will produce a UTF-8 encoded text file with your data:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes,
  EncdDecd;

const
  Data = 'PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8+DQo8c3RyaW5nPtiq2LPYqjwvc3RyaW5nPg==';

var
  Input: TStringStream;
  Output: TFileStream;

begin
  Input := TStringStream.Create(Data);
  try
    Output := TFileStream.Create('C:\desktop\out.txt', fmCreate);
    try
      DecodeStream(Input, Output);
    finally
      Output.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Input.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Or you could continue with `DecodeString`, but then immediately decode the UTF-8 text to a `WideString`. Like this:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes,
  EncdDecd;

const
  Data = 'PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8+DQo8c3RyaW5nPtiq2LPYqjwvc3RyaW5nPg==';

var
  Utf8: AnsiString;
  wstr: WideString;

begin
  Utf8 := DecodeString(Data);
  wstr := UTF8Decode(Utf8);
end.
```

If the content of the file can be represented in your application's prevailing ANSI locale then you can convert that `WideString` to a plain `AnsiString`.

```
var
  wstr: WideString;
  str: string; // alias to AnsiString
....
wstr := ... // as before
str := wstr;
```

However, I really don't think that using ANSI encoded text is going to lead to a very fruitful programming life. I encourage you to embrace Unicode solutions.

Judging by the content of the decoded data, it is XML. Which is usually handed to an XML parser. Most XML parsers will accept UTF-8 encoded data, so you quite probably can base64 decode to a memory stream using `DecodeStream` and then hand that stream off to your XML parser. That way you don't need to decode the UTF-8 to text and can let the XML parser deal with that aspect.

Comment: +1 And it is worth saying that UTF-8 is an Unicode solution, even for older versions of Delphi, as the OP is still using. http://www.utf8everywhere.org/ For simple process, using a WideString is the solution; but it has a performance cost (since BSTR memory allocation is very poor). You could use dedicated UTF-8 functions or classes, with Delphi 7, if needed, for a bigger project.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Agreed. I certainly did not mean to imply that UTF-8 is not Unicode.

Comment: Do note that `UTF8Decode()` (and `UTF8Encode()`) was broken in old versions of Delphi, including v7.  It was not a full UTF-8 implementation, it could not handle UTF-8 sequences above 3 bytes, for instance. It were finally fixed in D2009 (by getting rid of their manual UTF-8 implementation and let the OS do the encoding/decoding).

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to David Heffernan's awesome answer, and Remy Lebeau's note on how it's broken on Delphi 7, I would like to add a function that will help any developer stuck on Delphi 7.

Since `UTF8Decode()` is broken in Delphi 7, I found a function in a [forum](https://www.clubdelphi.com/foros/showthread.php?t=66966) that solved my problem:

```
function UTF8ToWideString(const S: AnsiString): WideString;
var
  BufSize: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  if Length(S) = 0 then Exit;
  BufSize := MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, PAnsiChar(S), Length(S), nil, 0);
  SetLength(result, BufSize);
  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, PANsiChar(S), Length(S), PWideChar(Result), BufSize);
end;
```

So now, you can use `DecodeString`, and then decode the UTF-8 text to a `WideString` using this function:

```
begin
  Utf8 := DecodeString(Data);
  wstr := UTF8ToWideString(Utf8);
end.
```